# Duplicate Column name in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm new to rails and following a tutorial where we created some entries. Currently when I run the server it tells me

```
Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
```

Then I noticed after seeing some SO posts, I should do things like run

```
rake db:migrate
```

Then I realized when I did that I got a bunch of lines and one which had this

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: description: ALTER TABLE "articles" ADD "description" text
```

Which I presume the problem comes from. Now i'm not an expert in rails, but how can I identify where this duplicate column is from, when I do

```
rails console- > Article.all
```

I get

```
    <ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Article id: 1, title: "This is my first article", 

description: "This is the description", created_at: "2016-07-20 00:03:42", 

updated_at: "2016-07-20 00:03:42">, #<Article id: 2, title: "This is an endited

 title", description: "This is my second description", created_at: "2016-07-20 

00:05:39", updated_at: "2016-07-20 00:40:54">]
```

Which I created yesterday. But where is this duplicate description field? Where should I be looking?

My two migration files look like this by the way

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Another

```
 class AddDescriptionToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        add_column :articles, :description, :text
        add_column :articles, :created_at, :datetime
        add_column :articles, :updated_at, :datetime
      end
    end
```

My schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160715020218) do

  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the second migration take out the line `add_column :articles, :description, :text`.  You already created a `description` column when you created the `articles` table in the first migration, with the line `t.text :description`:

```
create_table :articles do |t|
  t.string :title
  t.text :description
  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

That's the duplicate column Rails is referring to in the error.  Next time before you run migrations you can check `schema.rb` file to see what your database tables look like

Missed this the first time, but you also are duplicating your timestamp columns, `created_at` and `updated_at`  So the second migration is unnecessary

Comment: I added the schema in the original post. Its still giving me an error, and when i do rake db:migrate, it tells me i have a duplicate column somewhere else too

Comment: edited answer.  you are also duplicating your timestamp columns when your schema already has them

Comment: So do I delete everything in def change? Weird, the instructor DEFINITELY wrote all that in the last lecture. And his code works fine

Comment: i would just delete the entire migration file `AddDescriptionToArticles`.  It won't work as you already have those columns in your schema and Rails isnt letting you run it anyway

Comment: OHH now I remember what the instructor was saying. He was saying that if we forgot to add things like description in the create_articles.rb folder, do rails generate migration add_description_to_articles, and add it in the new migration file. I got mixed uop

Comment: Jeez rails sure is confusing. Thank you so much!

Comment: you're welcome.  just keep at it and learn from these types of errors.  they're great learning opportunities

Comment: But why does my instructor say it is better to create a new migration file like AddDescriptionToArticles, rather than rake db:rollback? Is that bad form?

Comment: It depends if you are working in a team and a version control like Git or not, if you are working in a team and your migration file has already been pushed to the remote branch, then yes always make a new file, because it is less hassle for the entire team, no need for everyone to rollback and migrate again and less chance of people forgetting to it and wasting time on unnecessary errors, simply creating a new migration means all eveyone needs to do is run the migration and carry on.

Comment: I see. Thanks! I'm just doing this for fun but ill keep that in mind

Comment: great answer, @JohnHayes-Reed

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting the error saying you have duplicate columns is because you simply are trying to add columns which already exist in your model.

lets run through your first migration file:

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

In the create_table block you have the following lines:
`t.string :title` <- this creates a title column of type string.
`t.text :description` <- this creates a description column of type text.
`t.timestamps, null: false` <- this creates two columns: `created_at` and `updated_at` both of type datetime with the not_null flag on them.

Now in your second migration file you are trying to add three columns:

```
add_column :articles, :description, :text
add_column :articles, :created_at, :datetime
add_column :articles, :updated_at, :datetime
```

But as we stated above they have already been created, and therefore are duplicates which can not be made. So the best option to solve your problem would be to just delete this second migration file where you are using add_column and everything should be ok.

Comment: Yes, I recall my instructor was just teaching us how to create a new migration file if we forgot to add something like the description. I thought we needed to include this, but since I already included description in the first migration file I'm fine. I just got confused. Rails sure is confusing haha! Thanks

Comment: Ahh, I see. Well glad its all now resolved! Have fun with the rest of your Ruby on Rails learning ;)